# npm start failed to parse json

Tags: json, node.js

This is different to many of these `failed to parse json` questions, Don't say `npm cache clean`, I have tried that before asking,

Before you ask me about my system details I will give them to you:

Using ubuntu xenial (16.04),
node version 4.2.6
npm version 3.8.8
In a crouton chroot
I'm x86_64

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/79016cdb389dd17d62a241836cf7fe31) is the npm-debug.log

The json consists of

```
    {
      "name": "tiny-game",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "main": "index.html",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "nw"
      }
    }
```

and thats it!

Comment: What is the path to your json file?

Comment: @Oleg /home/alex/nodews/tinyGame/package.json

Answer (score 0):

Do you have **Grunt's** command line interface installed globally?

If not, the command is:

```
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Then try:

```
npm install
```

Then:

```
npm start
```

I think this should fix your issue.

Comment: umm weird, lemme took a look to your npm log.

Comment: i know it sounds obvious but your last choice is to make a new project and see if your issue persists.

Comment: It doesn't... how? IT WORKS??

Comment: difficult to tell ! my top 2 guess are either the file structure was somehow wrong or the prob was related to the npm cache

Comment: Well, it wasnt to do with the npm cache, as i said in the question